# Radius of Convergence of a sparse Power Series

Tags: calculus

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp((2n)! + 4n^n) x^{(2n)!}
$$
I'm having trouble finding the radius of convergence of this power series.  Applying the ratio test yields a mess, and similarly the root test doesn't play well with the factorials.

Comment: Do you mean to sum over $n$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, over n.  I have fixed it now.